# OpenGL fixed pipeline rendered colour GL_FLOAT not precise enough

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using the OpenGL fixed pipeline to render 3D models where vertices are coded with GL_FLOAT RGB values. An example of vertex data in Wavefront OBJ format is shown below:

```
v -705.39 31.35 82.34 0.9780448 0.9807401 0.1518212
v -705.19 30.53 81.32 0.9780985 0.9799018 0.1514152
v -706.78 32.83 87.36 0.9776751 0.9822390 0.1538261
v -706.73 32.60 86.36 0.9776898 0.9820088 0.1534263
v -706.65 32.29 85.36 0.9777099 0.9816957 0.1530257
v -706.55 31.87 84.35 0.9777372 0.9812685 0.1526239
```

where each line starting with 'v' is a vertex, followed by its 3D positional coordinates, and then its RGB value in the range [0,1].

Below is a snippet of the rendering code:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(ww, wh); // Viewport is ww by wh in dimensions
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
glutCreateWindow("Rendered");

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(vfov, (GLdouble)ww / (GLdouble)wh, 500, 5000);
gluLookAt(cam_x, cam_y, cam_z, centre_x, centre_y, centre_z, up_x_norm, up_y_norm, up_z_norm);

display_object(); // Generates GL_TRIANGLES

// Read out colour pixels 
cv::Mat output_img(wh, ww, CV_32FC3);

glReadPixels(0, 0, ww, wh, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, (GLvoid *)output_img.data);
```

Upon inspecting some non-zero entries of output_img, they appear as follows:

```
0.003922 0.556863 0.525490
0.003922 0.552941 0.525490
0.003922 0.552941 0.525490
0.003922 0.552941 0.521569
0.003922 0.552941 0.521569
0.003922 0.552941 0.521569
0.003922 0.552941 0.521569
0.003922 0.552941 0.521569
0.003922 0.552941 0.521569
0.003922 0.552941 0.521569
0.003922 0.552941 0.521569
0.003922 0.552941 0.521569
0.003922 0.552941 0.521569
0.003922 0.549020 0.517647
0.003922 0.549020 0.517647
0.003922 0.549020 0.517647
0.003922 0.549020 0.517647
0.003922 0.549020 0.517647
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.552941 0.521569
0.007843 0.552941 0.521569
0.007843 0.552941 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
0.007843 0.549020 0.521569
```

It seems that there are multiple entries of the same colour due to insufficient intermediate precision in the fixed pipeline.

What are the necessary settings to compute the rendered colour values to a higher precision?

Comment: The colors of the fragments are stored in the framebuffer. The format of the default framebuffer is (probably) 1 byte for each color channel. So it doesn't matter which type you use when you read the color from the buffer. The precision is lost when the color is written into the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors of the fragments are stored in the framebuffer. The format of the [Default Framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer) is (probably) 1 byte for each color channel. So it doesn't matter which type you use when you read the color from the buffer. The precision is lost when the color is written into the buffer.

If you want to store the colors with a higher precision, then you've to render to a [Framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object), that uses a [Renderbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) or [Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture) with a format that can store the values with an higher precision.
See [Image Format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format).

If you want to render to a framebuffer, then I recommend to read a tutorial like [Framebuffers](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers) or [Render To Texture](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) respectively [Khronos wiki - Framebuffer Object Extension Examples](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Extension_Examples#Quick_example.2C_render_to_buffer_.28p-buffer_replacement.29).

Comment: Thank you. I managed to use the code snippet in https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Extension_Examples#Quick_example.2C_render_to_buffer_.28p-buffer_replacement.29 to achieve better precision.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious suggestion here is to use an FBO with a 32bit floating point RGB colour target (rather than relying on the 8bits per channel default used for the default frame buffer).